# Queue a Bash script to run after currently job finishes?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to start a Bash script, and then queue up other bash scripts to start when the first one is done?

For context. I’m doing image processing where I need to manually fiddle with and image and then send it to a command line utility to get finished up. I only have the resources to run 1 instances of utility (a huge neural net), but I can still keep searching for and editing more images to feed it later. I would like to be able to throw jobs on a queue the second I’m done with the manual part.

Comment: Are you looking to add to a command that you've already run, or that you haven't run yet?  e.g., is  `&&` [as in `touch /tmp/file && ls /tmp/file``] what you want? Or are you looking to watch  a running process out of band, then execute $thing?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use GNU Parallel with `-j1`:

```
true >jobqueue; tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel -j1
```

Append job:

```
echo my_command my_arg >> jobqueue
```

For more options (such as running when a new file is put in a dir) see: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit more complicated than you want but I'll shoot.

Why not have a folder containing the images you have edited to be processed, then a cron job that checks that folder for images every minute or so and runs your finishing script on each item in that folder and then moves the completed image off to a 'finished' folder?